# Remove UIWebView selection highlight?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

So in a UIWebView, whenever you press anything, a grey selection box appears. Like this:

[image]

I know you can remove it if you have access to the source code of the website, but obviously in this example I'm using YouTube, which I cannot access. Can I remove the grey highlight within Xcode?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why not use JavaScript-injection?

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.body.style.setProperty(\"-webkit-tap-highlight-color\", \"rgba(0,0,0,0)\");"
];
```

Comment: Putting this in the viewDidLoad doesn't seem to do anything - am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you need to adjust something on the JavaScript, I don't know, I've just come up with this quickly. Just in order to push you in the right direction.

Comment: man, just use the css instead of viewDidLoad.

a {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color : rgba(0,0,0,0);
}